# Generate Excel .xls from .drl in JBoss Drools 4

Tags: excel, jboss, drools

Is it possible with the drools4 api generate a decision table spreadsheet (.xls) from a .drl file?

Comment: I think subject is wrong. change it so that anyone looking for same thing can find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for this in Drools. You can only generate DRL from XLS.